# Is $\max(f)$ well defined if $f$ is finite?

Tags: real-analysis

Say I have a function that's finite almost everywhere within an interval $[a,b]$. Does that mean that it has an upper bound if I ignore those points on which it is infinite? i.e. is:

$$\text{max}_{[a,b]}(f)$$

well defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for one of two possible reasons:

1) The function may still be unbounded in $[a,b]$. Bounded and finite are not the same concept. Bounded means there is a number $M<\infty$ such that $|f(x)|<M$ for $x\in[a,b]$, whereas finite means that $|f(x)|<\infty$ for $x\in[a,b]$. This doesn't change if you say these properties hold almost everywhere.

2) Even if the function is finite a.e. in $[a,b]$, it may not achieve its supremum, in which case it has no maximum. There are conditions on $f$ that will guarantee it achieves its supremum (e.g. defined everywhere on a compact set and continuous), but under your minimal assumptions this cannot be guaranteed.

However, in the case that $f$ is unbounded on $[a,b]$ minus a null set and achieves $\infty$ on this null set, then if you allow yourself the extended real numbers you can take $\max_{[a,b]} f = \infty$.

Comment: I have that f is integrable. Does that help?

Comment: No, integrable functions are not good enough. One example: $[a,b]=[0,1]$, $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ for $x>0$, $f(0)=0$. $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ but it is unbounded and never equal to $\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

No: Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ if $x > 0$, and $f(0) = 0$. This is finite everywhere on $[0, 1]$, but has no meaningful maximum.

Your question seems related to the [essential supremum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum), which is defined to be the least $\alpha$ for which

$$|f(x)| \le \alpha$$

for almost every $x \in [a, b]$. But there are certainly functions (such as the one I described above) which are finite everywhere but are neither bounded nor essentially bounded.